# Is it possible to validate vendor folder integrity in composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I just inherited a composer project in a very bad shape. They sent me a zip file with the `vendor` directory in it and I suspect that the previous developer has edited files directly inside vendor.

Is there a way to "validate" the vendor folder to ensure that the files inside are unmodified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change the name of the old `vendor` to something else.
2. Execute `composer install` again.
3. Run `diff` to compare both directories.

E.g. for a sample project where I intentionally modified a single file inside `vendor`.

```
$ mv vendor vendor_old
$ composer install

### install output...

$ diff -rq vendor vendor_old

Files vendor/autoload.php and vendor_old/autoload.php differ
Files vendor/composer/autoload_files.php and vendor_old/composer/autoload_files.php differ
Files vendor/composer/autoload_real.php and vendor_old/composer/autoload_real.php differ
Files vendor/composer/autoload_static.php and vendor_old/composer/autoload_static.php differ
Files vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php and vendor_old/symfony/console/Terminal.php differ
```

You can mostly ignore the changes to the `autoload*` files, but with this listing you can concentrate in those other files that report differences (and run a more exhaustive `diff` from them).

In the example, only `vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php` was actually modified.

Comment: If you don't have a composer.lock, the version of packages might differ.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the project into some other folder, and delete the vendor directory. Run composer install and compare two vendor files.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is by using [`composer status`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#status) command.

The prerequisite is that package is installed from source (as described on the official Composer site):

> If you often need to modify the code of your dependencies and they are installed from source, the status command allows you to check if you have local changes in any of them.

Comment: `composer status` only works if your dependencies are installed from source, not if they comes as package.

Comment: @Mir thanks for the heads-up, I'll update the answer :)